# Value of type 'Timer' has no member 'invalidate'

Tags: swift, timer

Why am I not able to invalidate my timer? I keep getting an error that says:

> Value of type 'Timer' has no member 'invalidate'

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Below is my code.

```
var totalTimeInSec = Double()
var timer = Timer()
var timeInSec = 00.0
{
    didSet {
        if timeInSec <= 0 {
            timer.invalidate() // This is where the error occurs.
            startBtn.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        }
    }
}

func initialSettings() {
    timerSetting.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.settingTimer(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    //timerSetting.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CollectionViewController.collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}

func settingTimer(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let timeFormat = DateComponentsFormatter()
    timeFormat.allowedUnits = [NSCalendar.Unit.second, NSCalendar.Unit.minute, NSCalendar.Unit.hour]
    timeFormat.unitsStyle = DateComponentsFormatter.UnitsStyle.abbreviated
    timerLabel?.text = timeFormat.string(from: sender.countDownDuration)
    timeInSec = timerSetting.countDownDuration
    timeInSec = totalTimeInSec
}

@IBAction func timerStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Start" {
        resetCounter()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.changeLabelText), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startBtn.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        startBtn.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        showTimer.animate(fromAngle: showTimer.angle, toAngle: 0, duration: 0.5, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have used `timer.invalidate()` before with no problems, but can't seem to figure out why this is happening in this case.

Comment: I'll guess it's a matter of how things instantiate. You've defined `timer` as an instance variable (which is correct) but are trying to invalidate said variable as a property *before* it's actually part of the instance. If you are getting a build error (which I believe you are) than that's what's happening.

Comment: @dfd Modifying a property in a `didSet` observer is legal in Swift. My suggestion is to clean the project (Product > Clean) and see if that resolves the error.